# Cannot get http response when intervally requesting a new http request

Tags: java, httprequest, intervals

I have a class called `App` which is this one:

```
public class App{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        StreamingData dataStream = new StreamingData("urlString");
        dataStream.StreamHttpRequest();
    }
}
```

and this class called `StreamingData` that has two methods, the `StreamHttpRequest` that intervally calls the `httpRequest` every 1 second as shown below:

```
public class StreamingData {
    private String url;
    private JSONObject httpResponse;
    public StreamingData(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }
    public void httpRequest() throws Exception{
        try {
            URL obj = new URL(this.url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
                    InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            setHttpResponse(new JSONObject(response.toString()));
        } catch (ConnectException e){
            e.printStackTrace
        }
    }
    public void setHttpResponse(JSONObject httpResponse) {
        this.httpResponse = httpResponse;
    }
    public JSONObject getHttpResponse() {
        System.out.println(this.httpResponse.toString());
        return this.httpResponse;
    }
    public void StreamHttpRequest() {
        final long timeInterval = 1000;
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try {
                        httpRequest();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(timeInterval);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }
```

Whenever I call the `getHttpResponse` from the `httpRequest` method, or pretty much every method from the `StreamingData` class it returns the whole json response, but when I try to retrieve it from the `App` class like this

```
// code as shown above
StreamingData netDataStream = new StreamingData("urlString");
JSONObject netDataHttpResponse = netDataStream.getHttpResponse();
```

it returns `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` and the json is empty.

How can I get the json response to another class (e.g. the `App`)? Because for now I cannot use it outside the `StreamingData` class.

Thank you very much for your help, 
csymvoul

Comment: Try marking `httpResponse` as `volatile`. Also, read a bit about thread safety. You may be trying to access the data before it exists. Also, don't use a timed sleep loop for repetitive operations. Use `Timer` or `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: You mean something like that?

`private volatile JSONObject httpResponse;`

Comment: Yes. Note I updated the comment. Read all of it.

Comment: This is what I think it happens, As you said I try to access the data before it exist. But even if I use `Timer` the problem stil remains. How can I access the data from the `App`class? Is there a way to  collect the data after it is created in the `StreamingData` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with threads. That means that the httpResponse field value will be set once the http request performs (async).

here:

```
StreamingData netDataStream = new StreamingData("urlString");
JSONObject netDataHttpResponse = netDataStream.getHttpResponse();
```

You're asking for the response immediatelly (when the http response is not ready).

You could add some kind of listener to your StreamingData class , so that you can call on some method when the response is ready:

```
public class HttpResponseListener { 
    void onResponse(JSONObject httpResponse){...} 
}
```

Then you could do something like...

```
StreamingData netDataStream = new StreamingData("urlString" , new HttpResponseListener());
```

And call httpResponseListener.onResponse when the httpResponse object is set.

```
public void setHttpResponse(JSONObject httpResponse) {
    this.httpResponse = httpResponse;
    httpResponseListener.onResponse(httpResponse);
}
```

That is if you still want to use Http request / reponses with threads.

Comment: Hi Martin,
thank you very much for your answer.
Since I am totally new to Java, I haven't yet managed to check async programming, if this is what you are suggesting using. I am not sure I understand what to do with this `HttpResponseListener` class. You are saying that `onResponse` like be triggered only when the json object is not empty and then access it from the `App`? Also you mention that this is the way to go if i want to use threads. Do you suggest another, easier (hopefully) way to go?

Comment: Well if you have to make a http request every second and do something with the response then using an observer pattern or listeners is a way to go. The HttpResponseListener class should have a onResponse method that receives the httpResopnse object and do something with it. You shall call the onResponse method on the httpResponseListener object within the StreamingData#setHttpResponse method.

Comment: The HttpResponseListener#onResponse method should dictate what to do with the HttpResponse object. The StreamingData class should have a HttpResponseListener parameter in it's constructor